# How to get `git-p4 sync` to work?

Tags: git-p4

I've successfully created a git branch called 'scaffold' by using `git-p4.py clone`.

I now want to sync the latest Perforce changes into the git branch so I'm trying `git-p4.py sync  --branch=scaffold` but all that happens is the output of the following:

```
Syncing with origin first, using "git fetch origin"
Creating/updating branch(es) in refs/remotes/p4/ based on origin branch(es)
Performing incremental import into scaffold git branch
Depot paths: //depot/depot/path/to/code/
No changes to import!
```

After that, `git status` says `nothing to commit (working directory clean)`.

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me on my desktop but fails with `fast-import failed` on Jenkins:

```
git checkout scaffold
git p4 sync --branch=scaffold //depot/path/to/code/...@all
git push ssh://git@example.com:7999/repository/project.git +remotes/p4/scaffold:scaffold
```